# TCP Communication in android

Tags: android, networking, logging, tcp, tcpclient

I am trying to communicate Arduino UNO with android phone, What I trying to is

http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno

1) android device post a string to arduino

2) arduino post a integer to android

So far I can post message from android , received in Arduino board, but I **can not post a integer to android , nothing receive at android**

**Arduino Code** (Which can receive character "a", "b", "c", "d", and for case "z", I would like to send back the distance which is an int)  :

```
void loop()
{ 
  distance = Dist.getDistanceCentimeter();
  if(distance<=5 & distance>1)
  {
    back();
    delay(100);
    ting();
    distance=0;
  } 
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    lkf = Serial.read();
  switch(lkf)
  {
  case 'a':
     front();
     servoX.write(90);
     lkf=0;  
     break;   
   case 'b':
     back();
     lkf=0;
     break;     
   case 'c':
     left();
     lkf=0;
     break;
   case 'd':
     right();
     lkf=0;
     break; 
  case 'z':
    Serial.write(distance);
    break; 
    }
  }
 }
```

**Android Code:**

**In Main Activity**

```
@Override
protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

    //create TCPClient object 
    mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
        @Override
        //check whether server return message
        public void messageReceived(String message) {
            f_sensor.setText(message);
            Log.d("test1","msg rece" + message);
            //publishProgress(message);
        }
    });
    mTcpClient.run();

    return null;
}
```

**TCP Cilent**

```
public class TCPClient {

    private String serverMessage;
    public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.8.1"; //your computer IP address
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 2001;
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    private boolean mRun = false;

    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;

    /**
     *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message){
        if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    public void stopClient(){
        mRun = false;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            try {

                //send the message to the server
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

                //receive the message which the server sends back
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {
                    serverMessage = in.readLine();

                    if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                    }
                    serverMessage = null;

                }

                Log.d("test1",serverMessage);
                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping

**Note:** I found some fact about the board, is there any hints about that?

The binary representation of integers varies between Arduino (16 bit) and Android (32) bit, and while both an Arduino and most native-level Android implementations are little-endian, Android java code is big-endian.

Comment: I don't know how you can post the message since you're not calling `sendMessage` anywhere in the posted code. Also everything in your class should be `private` unless you have a good reason not to make it `private`.

Comment: The distance is an int. Well ok. But it is up to you if you sent four integer bytes or two. Or if you send the value as string. Where the sting contains digits.

Comment: You're reading lines but you aren't writing lines. The `readLine()` method will block until a line terminator or end of stream occurs or an exception isnthrown.

Comment: I think it is caused by the arundio side type problem, the serial write is writing bytes to android , which fail if I supply a integer to this function. All problem fix right now